# Inserting data into table using apache spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to insert data into an empty table in database :

**Spark Version : 2.3.0**

**No. of records to be inserted : 10 Million**

***Method 1:***

```
outputDataSet.write().format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "XYZ").save();
```

**Output** : error saying table already exists.

***Method 2 :***

```
outputDataSet.write().insertInto("XYZ");
```

**Output** : error saying Table or view doesn't exist.

I read documentation for `insertInto(String tableName)` it says :

*Because it inserts data to an existing table, format or options will be ignored.*

I am not sure how to insert data in existing db table using apache spark.

**EDIT**

***Method 3 :***

```
 outputDataSet.write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "XYZ").save();
```

**Output** : Process keeps running but nothing is being written in the table at the end I had to kill the process as it didn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
outputDataSet.write.format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "XYZ").mode("overwrite").save();
```

Comment: Why do I overrite the data? I just need to insert the data.

Comment: It is not supported. update function .
One option is to use an action (foreach, foreachPartition) with standard JDBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the code below. This will create the table if it does not exist and append the data if the data already exists

```
outputDataSet.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("ABC");
```

can u try this one as well

outputDataSet.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("my_table")

Comment: but will it take the connection to the correct DB? as here connection is not provided, also in spark 2.3.0. mode(append) is the method instead of mode(SaveMode.Append)

Comment: I tried and Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: XYZ; error is thrown because of reason mentioned in above comment

Comment: are you pointing to the correct schema,for eg schema.tableName? rather than using the default

Comment: you will have to provide the additional parameters such as connection and format("jdbc").i have just pasted the jist of the code

Comment: I have used String connection = "jdbc:oracle:thin:Username/password@//password:PORT/SERVICENAME"; to load the data from db and using same to persist the data

Comment: That is what I have mentioned in the question spark documentation says : for insertInto(String tableName) it says :

Because it inserts data to an existing table, format or options will be ignored.
So even if I add options reagarding connection and format that is ignored

Comment: I have tried saveAsTable as well it also goes to endless processing and doesn't insert any data to the table.